# Error 500 and CORS : what's the difference between $http and $window.XMLHttpRequest

Tags: angularjs, http, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

In one of my angularJS project, i decided to use [ng-droplet](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ngDroplet), which allow me to create drag-n-drop zone to upload images on server via my api.

After setting the plugin, I tried it, but i get :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi.com/api/items. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to " * " on server side, and i have no problem to do requests on my other api endpoints.

So I tried to see how the plugin create the request and send it, here's how :

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function uploadFiles() {

                // Reset...
                $scope.isError = false;

                var httpRequest   = new $window.XMLHttpRequest(),
                    formData      = new $window.FormData(),
                    queuedFiles   = $scope.filterFiles($scope.FILE_TYPES.VALID),
                    fileProperty  = $scope.options.useArray ? 'file[]' : 'file',
                    requestLength = $scope.getRequestLength(queuedFiles),
                    deferred      = $q.defer();

                // Initiate the HTTP request.
                httpRequest.open('post', $scope.options.requestUrl, true);

                /**
                 * @method appendCustomData
                 * @return {void}
                 */
                (function appendCustomData() {

                    if (!$scope.options.disableXFileSize) {

                        // Setup the file size of the request.
                        httpRequest.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', requestLength);

                    }

                    // ...And any other additional HTTP request headers, and POST data.
                    $scope.addRequestHeaders(httpRequest);
                    $scope.addPostData(formData);

                })();

                /**
                 * @method attachEventListeners
                 * @return {void}
                 */
                (function attachEventListeners() {

                    // Define the files property so that each listener has the same interface.
                    $scope.listeners.files       = queuedFiles;
                    $scope.listeners.deferred    = deferred;
                    $scope.listeners.httpRequest = httpRequest;

                    // Configure the event listeners for the impending request.
                    $scope.listeners.progress();
                    $scope.listeners.success();
                    $scope.listeners.error();

                })();

                // Iterate all of the valid files to append them to the previously created
                // `formData` object.
                $angular.forEach(queuedFiles, function forEach(model) {
                    formData.append(fileProperty, model.file);
                });

                // Voila...
                $scope.isUploading = true;

                httpRequest.send(formData);
                return deferred.promise;

            };
```

As you can see, he's not using $http but $window.XMLHttpRequest.

So I tried to do a file upload in a test controller, on the same end point ( http://myapi.com/api/items ), but this time with $http.

Like so :

```
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadedFile');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', "rfsdfsd");
    formData.append('description', "rfsdfhgfhfgsd");
    formData.append('category', 1);
    formData.append('price', 20);
    formData.append('file', file);



    $http.post('http://myapi.com/api/items', formData, {

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    });
```

Note the **'Content-Type': undefined**, because when i tried this one, it worked ! Files are actually uploaded and i get a 200 response code.

If i change the Content-Type from undefined to "multipart/form-data", or anything else, or if i remove that line, i got the error from above and upload fail.

In the angular documentation, it is said that setting Content-Type to "undefined" explicitly remove the header :

> To explicitly remove a header automatically added via $httpProvider.defaults.headers on a per request basis, Use the headers property, setting the desired header to undefined.

It seems that the fact of removing the Content-Type header is part of the reason that it works with $http.

So I also tried with a $window.XMLHttpRequest inside this test controller :

```
                var httpRequest = new $window.XMLHttpRequest();

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadedFile');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', "rfsdfsd");
    formData.append('description', "rfsdfhgfhfgsd");
    formData.append('category', 1);
    formData.append('price', 20);
    formData.append('file', file);

    httpRequest.open('post', 'http://myapi.com/api/items', true);
    httpRequest.send(formData);
```

But this one give me the same CORS error as before. I also tried to manually add a Content-Type header like this :

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', undefined);
```

or

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', null);
```

or "", " " etc but nothing seemed to work, i always got :

```
POST http://myapi.com/api/items 400 (Bad Content-Type header value: &#39;undefined&#39;)
```

So, why does it work with $http and Content-Type set to undefined and how can i modify ng-droplet to make it work ? ( i don't want to rewrite the whole thing using $http instead of $window.XMTHttpRequest).

Why do i get this error when using $window.XMTHttpRequest or $http without Content-Type header or with Content-Type set to anything but undefined ?

**Ps** : If anyone ask : ng-droplet provides its own way to add POST data, which are needed on the endpoint that i use. Like so :

```
$scope.interface.setPostData({title: "test", description: 'testetstsetest', price: 20, category: 1});
```

So it's not the problem source.

---

**EDIT :**

I solved it, I forgot that I had an Http Interceptor which automatically add a Authorization header to all the $http requests. The thing that I didn't know was that it wasnt added to $window.XMLHTTPRequest. So I added it manually and now it works.

---

Comment: Your `500 Internal Error` looks suspicious. Do you have the logs of the server (or the http response) to know what's wrong ? If the server code looks like "handle request, prepare response, add CORS headers, send" but fails too early, you will get what you see here: a 500 error without CORS headers. In that case, the CORS issue is not the cause but the consequence.

Comment: Problem solved. See my Edit above, thanks for your concern !